# How to create times series array for chart.js with flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have some python code which sucessfully passes two array to my html template

```
@app.route('/line')
def line():
    df= av_query(av_start_date,av_end_date,'44201')
    df['dt']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
    df['RawValue']=np.where(df['Units']=='007',df['RawValue']*1000,df['RawValue'] )
    temp_df=df[df['Site']=='SM']
    dates = temp_df['dt']
    values = temp_df['RawValue']


    return render_template('line.html', title='Ozone Data',dates=dates[:5], values=values[:5], max_n=100)
```

and in my html template I have tested this plotting code

```
  <center>
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
        
        
        
        <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
        
        <script>
            



            var s1 = {
              label: 's1',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              data: [
                { x: '2017-01-06 18:39:30', y: 100 },
                { x: '2017-01-07 18:39:28', y: 101 },
              ]
            };

            var s2 = {
              label: 's2',
              borderColor: 'red',
              data: [
                { x: '2017-01-07 18:00:00', y: 90 },
                { x: '2017-01-08 18:00:00', y: 105 },
              ]
            };
                        
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'line',
              data: { datasets: [s1, s2] },
              options: {
                scales: {
                  xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time'
                  }]
                }
              }
            });

        </script>
      </center>
```

How do I replace the dummy data in `s1` and `s2` with my data?

I tried to push each line to the dataset but that did not seem work.

```
    var s1 = {
      label: 's1',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      dates=dates
      values=values
      data: []
      for (i=0; i<=dates.length; i++){
      data.push({x:dates[i], y:values[i]})
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to do this is render a variable in the page using the template.

If your data is in an array or dictionary, make sure to convert it to json before passing it to the template, then pass it to the javascript when the template renders like so:

```
<script>
   const data = {{ data|safe }};
</script>
```

JSON will natively render as Javascript and you can do with it what you will then.

Make sure you pass it through the `safe` filter or it will just be escaped.